# Python webscraping a form that uses Javascript to process request

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the resulting page from this page:

http://data.philly.com/philly/property/

I am using 254 W Ashdale St as my trial entry, when I do that in my browser it directs me to the result I'm looking for in the HTML (same URL though).

Python requests is successfully putting the address I put in in the results page, but I am not able to get the owner information, which is what I am trying to scrape. I have been trying with Selenium and phantomjs, nothing I am doing is working.

I was also confused about the form action, it seemed to just be the same URL as the page the form is on.

I appreciate any and all advice or help!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium takes care of virtually everything, just find the elements, enter the information, find the button, click on it, then go to the owner, click on it and get scrap the info you need.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://data.philly.com/philly/property/')

#enter the street address
driver.find_element_by_name('LOC').send_keys('254 W Ashdale St')
#click on the submit button
driver.find_element_by_name('sendForm').click()

#find the owner
owner_tag = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[2]
owner = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[2].text
print(owner)

#click on the owner
owner_tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()

#get the table with the relevant info    
rows = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

#get the row with the sale prices
sale_prices = list()
for row in rows:
    sale_prices.append(row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[4].text)

print('\n'.join(sale_prices))
```

Output:

> ```
> FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
> $123,600.00
> $346,100.00
> [..]
> $789,500.00
> ```